# background size cover only works with mobile in inline-style

Tags: html, css

I have weird problem with `background-size:cover` in CSS, since it only works in mobile when I specify as inline-styling, at least in iphone 5 mode of Chrome Dev Tool. Does anyone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

That might be any of the following reasons:

**Reason 1:**
That might be the override problem.

Try to use !important:

```
div{
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Or do select the specific selector.

**Reason 2:**
Another reason might be of cache.

Clear the cache from your mobile by using setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have the problem override, sure of it. 

Cache is cleared.
I will post my example on jsfiddle soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have found background-size: cover; to be problematic, I think you will find this for example works better:

```
 @media only screen
    and (max-device-width : 899px)
    {
        body #wrapper
        {
       -webkit-background-size: contain auto;
          -moz-background-size: contain auto;
          -o-background-size: contain auto;
          background-size: contain auto;
         }
    }



@media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 900px) and (max-device-width : 1900px)
    {
        body #wrapper
        {
         -webkit-background-size: contain auto;
          -moz-background-size: contain auto;
          -o-background-size: contain auto;
          background-size: contain auto;
        }
}


@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 1901px)
{
    body #wrapper
    {
     -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
      -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
      -o-background-size: 100% auto;
      background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it work better, it doesn't seem to have the cover in it. Hmm, I don't know if contain auto does the same thing ? Can you explain a bit clearer.

Comment: It was what achieved my goal, that's all I can say.